# Convert Text to Date in Excel Problems

Tags: excel, excel-2010

So I open excel, in G2 put this: Feb/12/2016 01:09:28 PM UTC

Then in any other cell try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(G2,11),"Dec",12),"Nov",11),"Oct",10),"Sep",9),"Aug",8),"Jul",7),"Jun",6),"May",5),"Apr",4),"Mar",3),"Feb",2),"Jan",1))+TIMEVALUE(MID(G2,13,11)),"Error")
```

I am trying to get it to show like 2/12/2016 13:09

But its giving me my error. Iv tried everything, just not working??

Many thanks guys

Comment: Where does it 'fail' and produce your custom 'Error'.message? (Use the "Evaluate Formula" functionality under the "Formulas"-tab to do a step-by-step evaluation of the formula). Your formula produces the correct result when I past it into my own excel...

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you made sure to update your delimiter setting so that comma and not semi-colon is used to separate parts of a formula? (As you have South Africa listed as your location in your profile, I mean)

Comment: I put this in G2 to make this easier to trace, =DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(G2,11),"Feb",2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(G2,13,11)) and I did a trace and it seems that the "Feb" is the problem. I get #VALUE. if i change it to just Feb then I get the #NAME problem.

Comment: As a test: What do you get if you enter =DATEVALUE("1/2/2018") ? Do you get January 2nd (43102) or February 1st (43132)?

Comment: If i use =TEXT(35,"mmm") I get Feb. If I use =TODAY() I get 2018/07/19 and If I use =DATEVALUE("1/2/2018") I get #VALUE!

Answer (score -1):

### Short answer:

Use the following formula:

`=DATE(MID(A1,8,4),MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3)),MID(A1,5,2)) +  IF(MID(A1, 22,2) = "PM",  TIME(MID(A1, 13, 2), MID(A1, 16, 2), MID(A1, 19, 2)) + TIME(12, 0, 0), TIME(MID(A1, 13, 2), MID(A1, 16, 2), MID(A1, 19, 2)))`

---

### Long answer:

While not necessary, it's probably better to separate Time and Date
for data manipulation.

What I'd recommend is to use hidden columns, this makes your date nice and neatly separated, but furthermore will also help me explaining the answer rather than just pasting a giant formula:

> *Under presumption your text information always has the same format*   `"Mon"/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM UTC`

**In cell B1, we'll paste our date**:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,8,4),MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3)),MID(A1,5,2))
```

Pretty self explanatory, we'll extract individual parts of the date format and apply it to them. The only trick part is using the `MONTH()`function to convert the String of Month to an actual Month format.

---

**Now to the time, a bit more tricky**:

Let's try to parse it in C1:

First, we'll need to implement an `IF` function, that will convert AM/PM format to 24h format and then we'll use string functions, similarly like in date above to extract data to our `TIME()` funciton.

```
=IF(MID(A1, 22,2) = "PM",  TIME(MID(A1, 13, 2), MID(A1, 16, 2), MID(A1, 19, 2)) + TIME(12, 0, 0), TIME(MID(A1, 13, 2), MID(A1, 16, 2), MID(A1, 19, 2)))
```

---

Last but not least, in the column D we'll paste our result.
First make sure your format is set properly to your expected output:

[image]

and then we'll simply add our two data fields together:

```
=B1 + C1
```

**Produces the expected result:**

[image]