# How to read time stamp (DD/MM/YYYY) format from text file and correctly interpret it using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I need to write an Excel VBA program to read a text file and sort them by timestamp. Following is an example of the text file:

```
Time / Date ColumnB Column C
3/03/2017 3:07  Value B2 Value C2
3/02/2018 9:02  Value B4 Value C4
16/02/2018 9:03 Value B5 Value C5
17/02/2018 9:04 Value B6 Value C6

(File Name: import_File.csv)
```

where the time / Date is in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM format.

However, when I try to open it in VBA, it have automatically interpreted the first column incorrectly by following American format (MM/DD/YYYY)

```
File            |Correct interpretation |VBA interpretation
----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------
3/03/2017 3:07  |3 Mar 2017 3:07:00     |3 Mar 2017 3:07
3/02/2018 9:02  |3 Feb 2018 9:02:00     |2 Mar 2018 9:02
16/02/2018 9:03 |16 Feb 2018  9:03:00   |"16/02/2018  9:03:00" as a text
17/02/2018 9:04 |17 Feb 2018  9:04:00   |"17/02/2018  9:04" as a text
```

Following is how do I open the file:

> Set Data_File = Application.Workbooks.Open("import_File.csv", 3, True, 1)

I do tried to use *Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"*, but it doesn't help at all as it have already interpreted the column incorrectly when it first come in.

Should I need to open it as a text file first, then play around the timestamp myself? Or there is any quicker way to do the job.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you done a search on here? Many questions and answers about dates and formatting....

Comment: I answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51418890/5512705) yesterday

Comment: Hi Vegard, I open the csv file  using application.workbook.open.

Comment: The mentioned format it not "DD/MM/YYYY", but "D/MM/YYYY" (there's no leading zero in the day number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If your local settings use the same date format as the one you describe you want*, add the `Local:=True` qualifier to `Workbook.Open` to force the interpretation of dates to follow your computer's local settings (instead of the default EN-US interpretation that is built into VBA).

Example:

```
Set Data_File = Workbooks.Open Filename:="import_File.csv", ReadOnly:=True, Format:=1, Local:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below sample code for your solution.

```
Sub csvx()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    strPath = Path & "C:\root\abc.csv"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=strPath & strFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Local:=True

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("C1:C4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

   ActiveWorkbook.Save
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

> This is range of date column start to end e.g. C1:C4

**Sample CSV File**

[image]

**CSV FILE DATA**

Name,Age,Date
ewr,43,20-Mar
ewrwe,23,11-Oct
wee,34,11-Nov